# Possible to change database display name (without actually renaming) in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am working on a shared server where I can create a large number of MySQL databases using the providers admin panel.

The databases are created automatically with names which are build using my customer number + a counter. **I cannot change these names.** So when working in phpMyAdmin I a see a long list of databases with names like:

```
db11223344_1
db11223344_2
db11223344_3
...
db11223344_n
```

This makes working with the databases quite hard since I have to remember which database contains which data.

Is it possible to change the **display name** of the database without changing the actual database name? I would like to see a list like:

```
wordpress
myProjectXY
shop
...
DatabaseN

// OR Notes / Comments
db11223344_1 (wordpress)
db11223344_2 (myProjectXY)
db11223344_3 (shop)
...
db11223344_n (DatabaseN)
```

Is this possible in phpMyAdmin? Or does MySQL itself has a feature to add a different **display name** to a database which can be used in phpMyAdmin?

---

**EDIT:**

I don't think that this question is a duplicate of the linked question. This is **NOT** about creating an actual alias for a database which can actually be used to work with the database (this is what the linked question is asking).

This is just about changing the **display name** of a database within phpMyAdmin. This name does not need to be available / known anywhere outside phpMyAdmin.

Keeping the original database name as display name and adding a custom name/note would also be fine.

Is something like this possible in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: And then we would see questions like I have database xxx (phpmyadmin screenshot attached), but mysql tells me database xxx does not exist.

Comment: @Shadow This could happen of course but in my opinion this would not be a good argument against such a useful feature. Using notes/comments instead (see my edit) would easily solve this... However, I guess your answer is "No this is not possible"?

Comment: I disagree on how important this feature is, but there you go, see the 2nd answer to the duplicate question if you want to go ahead.

Comment: @Shadow This question is explicitly about NOT changing the database name but just about changing the display name in phpMyAdmin. Thus this question is not a duplicate of "How to create a database alias". An alias can be used to actually work with the database. The display name is just a label in phpMyAdmin...

Comment: You should re-read your own question: `Or does MySQL itself has a feature to add a different display name / alias to a database which can be used in phpMyAdmin?` Hence the duplicate.

Comment: I find it very *interesting* to decide whether the question is a duplicate based on just **one** word. I think the whole rest of the question makes it more than clear that here NO alias in the technical sense is meant but a display name in phpMyAdmin. If it serves the matter I remove this one word of course with pleasure...

Comment: It's an entire sentence formulated as a question, not just one word. If it is truly a functionality in phpmyadmin you are asking about, then you are in the wrong site anyway, as the question has nothing to do with software development, nor with IDEs without the mysql part.